# Timeshift backup to Samba NAS drive

Tags: backup, nas, timeshift

I have a Samba NAS that I would like to be able to backup to using Timeshift. I am able to mount it to a folder via cifs-utils, but it does not show as an available local drive in timeshift. Mounting it in the /timeshift folder does nothing either, timeshift copies to the local folder instead of the network one.

Is there a way to mount the NAS as a local drive so Timeshift can find it and backup to it?

Comment: As far as I know, TS only works with Linux partitions, and uses rsync or BTRFS snapshots. See https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift

Comment: My NAS is using an ext4 formatted drive, though

Comment: Yes, but you're accessing it via SMB or CIFS, yes? If you connect the drive directly to your PC it'll work.

Comment: I know, but I would like to be able to have it backup over the network, instead of having to connect a drive every time to backup. My laptop also doesn't have enough space to locally store backups.

Comment: Your last sentence confuses me. No local space is used.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to automatically backup over wireless, instead of directly connecting the drive to my laptop

Comment: Backup over wireless?!? I wouldn't trust backups done over wireless. I know... Apple did it... but they don't make those Time Machine base stations any more...

Comment: In the end I used Ubuntu's included deja dup, backing up to the mounted NAS, which works fine for my purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Glad you found a working solution.

Comment: I still can't find any reasoning or workaround for this. My SMB mount is a SATA hard disk and the device I'm trying to back up is a low power semi-embedded device with only a single USB-C port, so no option for a physical connection.

Comment: I don't understand the incredulity of backing up over wireless, it's not like latency spikes would pose a problem. Time machine over wireless to Ubuntu SMB server has been BY FAR the most reliable backup and restore tool I've ever used.

Comment: I'm thinking of simply backing up to the local disk and copying over the resulting snapshot files to the SMB server after Timeshift finishes. But this will only work while <50% disk usage, and even at 49% there won't be much free working space...

Comment: Hi, it's been a while, after trying every backup program here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Synchronization_and_backup_programs I found that while it doesn't have a GUI, restic has been by far the best and most reliable backup tool for me. If you aren't restricted to timeshift backups, setting up a recurring restic backup through cron could be a solution. You could mount the SMB share as a folder or as an rclone destination to then backup to for restic.

Comment: Thanks! I was also thinking of trying Borg.